# How to convert text file into SQL insert statement?

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, file-io

I would upload a text file, and it will convert every row into a SQL insert statement, so it can insert into the database.

As my tried, there are 3 problems here:

1. it will insert 5 times the values at once
2. all the No. should be skip
3. As the strSQL, I need to insert the arrayOutput one by one to insert them all

Here is my text file

```
    No  Subject Code    Subject Name    Student ID  Student Name    Student Email   Lecturer Name   Lecturer Email
1   BSOA011 COMPUTERIZED PAYROLL    1751234-BSOA    WONG QI YI  dev.ng@outlook.com  LIM BEE HUI semd2019@gmail.com
2   SEMD008 COMPUTER NETWORKING 1851234-SEMD    LIM FENG FENG   dev.ng@outlook.com  NG WAI KONG semd2019@gmail.com
3   ITIN015 DISASTER RECOVERY MANAGEMENT    1851234-ITIN    HO DENG DENG    dev.ng@outlook.com  SZE CHEN NEE @ SOO CHEN NEE semd2019@gmail.com
4   ECOM004 WEB DEVELOPMENT SKILLS: WEB PROGRAMMING (PHP & MYSQL)   1851234-ECOM    KONG JIA WEN    dev.ng@outlook.com  TAN MING MING   semd2019@gmail.com
5   CGDD002 PRACTICAL ICT SKILLS    1951234-CGDD    CHONG SIAO YU   dev.ng@outlook.com  NG WAI KONG semd2019@gmail.com
```

Here is my code

```vb
 Private Sub ReadAndReplace()

    Dim file_contents As String = ""

    locationPath = Server.MapPath("~") & "File\" & filename

    If File.Exists(locationPath) Then
        Dim reader As StreamReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(locationPath)
        reader.ReadLine() 'skip first line


        Do While reader.Peek() <> -1
            file_contents += reader.ReadLine

            Dim arrayOutput As String() = Split(file_contents, vbTab)


            Dim errMessage As String = ""
            Dim strConn As String = "server=localhost;port=3306; user id=root;" _
                             & "password=;database=school;SslMode=none"
            Dim oDBCon As New MySqlConnection(strConn)
            Try
                oDBCon.Open()

                'INSERT RECORD
                Dim strSQL As String = "INSERT INTO studentinfo(subject_code, subject_name, student_id,
                                        student_name, student_email, lecturer_name, lecturer_email)VALUES('" _
                                        & arrayOutput(1) & "','" & arrayOutput(2) & "','" & arrayOutput(3) _
                                        & "','" & arrayOutput(4) & "','" & arrayOutput(5) _
                                        & "','" & arrayOutput(6) & "','" & arrayOutput(7) & "');"


                Dim oCommand2 As New MySqlCommand(strSQL, oDBCon)
                oCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Catch ex As Exception
                errMessage = ex.Message
            Finally
                oDBCon.Close()
            End Try
        Loop
        reader.Close()
    End If

End Sub
```

my output
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice this line:

```
file_contents += reader.ReadLine
```

It is adding to initial file_contents variable so when it is split to create arrayOutput the top 7 array elements are always the same.

Maybe try file_contents = reader.ReadLine so you only split one line per iteration.

Comment: I was just trying to debug but I didn't realize of this. Thanks anyway.